# What is the default value of initial-scale

Tags: html, tags, viewport, meta-tags

I have been reading [this article](https://css-tricks.com/probably-use-initial-scale1/) on `initial-scale`.

It mentions how to set the `initial-scale`, but what is the default value? I.e. when `initial-scale` is not set? (I know it could just be included) just interested what will happen if it is not.

For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

From this image (on the page above):

[image]

It does not seem to be `1` since it zooms.

Comment: Here’s the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#viewport-meta). It doesn’t clearly mention that either…

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not exactly sure what the default value would be, it seems that the value is bad in a lot of examples. Without initial scale, you could possibly get a zooming bug in rotation and media queries for the landscape mode being ignored.

Check out this link for examples that are done with and without initial-value.
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mobile-viewport-orientations-initial-scale-1-0/38495/11